# Не работает привязка события на checkbox

Tags: jquery, mobile, javascript, galaxy

День добрый!

Столкнулся с таким моментом, не работает привязка события на изменение состояния чекбокса. Галочка ставится, а функция по событию не выполняется.

Из [документации](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/checkboxes/events.html):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Не работает именно в родном браузере(webkit), в установленном Firefox работает, в iPad работает, на компе работает(chrome).

Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Comment: А если bind("click") сделать?

Comment: Тоже самое, jquery mobile добавляет много своего кода, поэтому прямой клик не работает.

Comment: Курите консоль. Там наверняка какие-то ошибки есть.

Comment: В планшетах нет консоли((

Comment: Пока решил вопрос прописываем функции в теге, onclick="..."

Comment: Некоторые бразеры не воспринимают событие onchange на checkbox, поэтому правильным решением использовать onclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробовали заменять bind?

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event, ui) {
      ...
    });
```

Вот так например. Еще попробуйте привязать к checkbox id или class и обращаться конкретно по не нему.